# point with multiple texts in open layers 3

Tags: openlayers, style

I have a map with vectorial features, represented with a text as icon with font awesome:

```
new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: '\uf005',
          font: 'normal 14px FontAwesome',
          textAlign: 'center',
          textBaseline: 'middle',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'white',
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'black',
            width: 5
          })
        })
      })
```

Now i need to add a real text as label, of course with other font.

Is there any way to add 2 texts, with different configuration to the same feature?

Comment: it doesn't support `text` as an array to set multiple text styles. so you need new style for second text style.

Comment: you can set `style` as an array instead `text`